# Red5Pro SDK Error when I use domain name instead of IP Address

Tags: android, sdk, red5pro

I was working with the Red5 Android App Example and I saw that when I use the domain name instead of the ip address it show me an error:

I/r5pro: Error closing main loop: resource busy or locked

Can someone explain what happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now the Android SDK only supports IP addresses. Red5 team is working on an update with domain support, but it's not released yet.

Answer (score 1):

we got the same error when working with Red5Pro iOS app examples. when is Red5 going to provide domain support for iOS...

Comment: As soon as the Red5Team give me the answer I will let you know.